# Nash Embedding Theorem where one quadratic equation is replaced by a linear one

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, riemannian-geometry, isometry

"Roughly", Nash embedding theorem is about the existence of $m$ (to be chosen) functions $x_i$ (of $n$ $u_j$) with some required order of differentiability and solutions of 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_j}  \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_k} = g_{jk} \qquad \forall j,k \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}:\ \ j\leq k$$
where $g_{jk}$ are the components of a Riemannian metric and the $u_j$'s are coordinates of a point in the manifold.

The local real-analytic version of the Nash Embedding Theorem as established by Janet, Cartan, or Burstin gives, for $m=n(n+1)/2$, an analytic solution.

I am interested in a variation on this problem where one of the quadratic equations above is replaced by a linear one. Precisely

**Question:** Does there exist $m$ (to be chosen) $C^1$ functions $x_i$  solutions of 
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{m} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_j}  \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial u_k} = g_{jk} \qquad \forall j \in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}
,  \quad
\forall k \in \{2,3,\ldots,n\}
:\ \ j\leq k
$$
and
$$\sum_{i=1}^{m} a_i  x_i = u_1$$
where $a_i$ are constants free to choose.

Note that the equation for $g_{11}$ is not in the list of quadratic equations. It is replaced by the (last) linear equation

**Motivation:** We want the hyperplanes $u_1$=constant to be totally geodesic in $\mathbb{R}^n$ equipped with some given metric $g$ and coordinates $(u_i)$. If this does not hold, I want this to be true in $\mathbb{R}^m$ ($m>n$) equipped with a metric which is an image of $g$ by an embedding $x$. The quadratic equations above are obtained by imposing further that this image metric is Euclidean (except for $g_{11}$). The linear equation just says that the image by $x$ of $u_1$=constant (in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is an hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Comment: What is $u_1$ supposed to be? Just some given function? It would be helpful to know something about the context of this question. Does it have some geometric significance?

Comment: Also, I think that calling the Janet/Cartan/Burstin result "the local version of the Nash embedding theorem" is misleading -- it's a local _real-analytic_ version. It's crucial that their result only works when the metric is real-analytic, which is a much stronger hypothesis than just a local version of Nash's theorem.

Comment: $u_1$ is just the first coordinate of $u$, a point say in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: I have added a motivation for my question. Thanks a lot for your comment about the difference between Janet/Cartan/Burstin result and Nash's one. I knew it bu-yt my words were too sloppy.